# applying a function to multiple lists (R)

Tags: r, lapply, mapply

I have two lists:

```
source <- list(c(5,10,20,30))
source.val <- list(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))
```

Each corresponding element in `source` has a corresponding value in `source.val`. I want to create dataframe from the above two files that look like below

```
source.val_5 source.val_10 source.val_20 source.val_30
  A            B             C             D
```

I did this

```
tempList <- list()
for(i in 1:lengths(source)){

  tempList[[i]] <- data.frame(variable = paste0('source.val_',source[[1]][[i]]),  
                                value = source.val[[1]][[i]])  
}
  
temp.dat <- do.call('rbind', tempList)        
temp.dat_wider <- tidyr::pivot_wider(finalList, id_cols = value, names_from = variable)
```

Now I want to do this across a bigger list

```
source <- list(c(5,10,20,30),
               c(5,10,20,30),
               c(5,10,20,30),
               c(5,10,20,30))
source.val <- list(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'),
                   c('B', 'B', 'D', 'D'),
                   c('C', 'B', 'A', 'D'),
                   c('D', 'B', 'B', 'D'))
```

The resulting table will have 4 rows looking like this:

```
  A tibble: 1 x 4
  source.val_5 source.val_10 source.val_20 source.val_30
    A            B             C             D      
    B            B             D             D
    C            B             A             D
    D            B             B             D
```

What is the best way to use function like mapply to achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the example shared, where all the elements of `source` have the same order you can do :

```
cols <- paste0('source.val_', sort(unique(unlist(source))))
setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, source.val), cols)

#  source.val_5 source.val_10 source.val_20 source.val_30
#1            A             B             C             D
#2            B             B             D             D
#3            C             B             A             D
#4            D             B             B             D
```

However, for a general case where every value in `source` do not follow the same order you can reorder `source.val` based on `source` :

```
source.val <- Map(function(x, y) y[order(x)], source, source.val)
```

and then use the above code.